# In Django, how can I reuse settings.py in a new app outside of the project

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I have a new Django application I am working on.

I have the following directory structure.

```
Django/
  appc
  project1
    appA
    appB
```

I would like to use the settings.py from project1 in appc.  I have added the appc application to the INSTALLED_APPS under project1. I am using WSGI so I added the Django/appc directory to the python path as well.

My problem comes in when I try and extend a template from appA I am not able to load any of the Variables defined in the project1 settins.py. So I guess my question is then how can I ensure that appC is going to source the settings from appB?

Comment: settings.py is never used with apps.

Comment: Ignacio, thank you, I guess I should fix that question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django apps that require access to the project settings should import and use [`django.conf.settings`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code).